# action script not working properly on menu

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have been working on flash website for a friend, based on a template, but i'm having some trouble with the menu, as when i click one of the links sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't.

Site: http://frrichardsonfeliz.com

Source files: http://frrichardsonfeliz.com/fla/rfelix_test.rar

As you can see, even the rollover does not even work properly.

I have been struggling with this for a week, and i don't know what to do anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I observed web page and my idea is it doesn't work when you click a menu item after a menu item click immidiately. So why there is problem like that?

Most of Flash templates builded by frame by frame, when you click menu item Flash plays movie and you lost the frame which have event listener for mouse clicks until animation stops. So you can add these event listeners manualy to these frames one by one. Or you can create new layer which contains whole frames and you can add your event listener to that one frame but it can make a conflict.